# Tamanho máximo do body de uma requisição POST

Tags: apache, http, post

Eu tenho um APP que envia dados via POST para um WEBSERVICE.
O problema é que eu tenho um campo BLOB (os dados dentro dele são gigantes) e eu chego a mandar mais ou menos 30 registros por requisição.
Minha dúvida é, existe uma quantidade máxima de dados que eu posso enviar via POST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta é simples, existe. Utilizando o comando [`phpinfo`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.phpinfo.php) você pode obter estas informações. Os campos relevantes do `phpinfo` sobre envio de dados, seriam estes abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

De acordo com a [documentação do PHP](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.file-uploads), segue explicações sobre cada configuração:

> **max_file_uploads (inteiro)**
>   O número máximo de arquivos simultâneos durante um upload. A partir do PHP 5.3.4 os campos em branco de arquivos não são contados para efeito desse limite.

---

> **max_input_nesting_level (inteiro)**
>   Configura a profundidade máxima de níveis das variáveis de entrada ( $_GET, $_POST).

---

> **max_input_time (inteiro)**
>   Configura o tempo máximo, em segundos, que um `script` é permitido despender interpretando dados de entrada, como `GET` e `POST`. O cronômetro começa no momento que o `PHP` é chamado pelo servidor e termina quando a execução começa.

---

> **max_input_vars (inteiro)**
>   Configura quantas variáveis de entrada serão aceitas, com o limite aplicado a cada super global `$_GET`, `$_POST` e `$_COOKIE` separadamente). O uso dessa diretiva mitiga a possibilidade de ataques de negação de serviço que utilizam colisões de `hash`. Se houver mais variáveis do que o especificado nessa diretiva um `E_WARNING` é lançado, e variáveis de entrada adicionais são ignorados.

---

> **memory_limit (inteiro)**
>   Define a quantidade máxima de memória em bytes que um `script` está permitido alocar. Isto ajuda a previnir que scripts mau escritos consumam toda memória disponível no servidor. Note que para não ter limite de memória, defina esta diretiva para -1.

---

> **post_max_size (inteiro)**
>   Configura o tamanho máximo dos dados postados. Essa configuração também afeta o `upload` de arquivos. Para receber `upload` de arquivos grandes, esse valor precisa ser maior que `upload_max_filesize`. De maneira geral `memory_limit` deve ser maior que `post_max_size`. Quando um `integer` é utilizado, o valor é medido em `bytes`. A resumida notação, como descrito neste FAQ, pode também ser usada. Se o dados postados forem maiores que `post_max_size` então as variáveis superglobais `$_POST` e `$_FILES` ficarão vazias. Isso pode ser observado de várias maneiras, por exemplo, por incluir uma variável no `array $_GET` ao chamar o `script` (chamar `<form action="edit.php?processed=1">`), então verificando se `$_GET['processed']` está preenchido.

---

> **upload_max_filesize (inteiro)**
>   O tamanho máximo de um arquivo enviado.

Estes valores podem ser configurados no `php.ini`. Caso estejam comentados, basta remover o comentário e configurar o valor desejado.